# Select Dropdown Splinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, splinter

I am trying to select an option from a drop down menu using Splinter. The script I'm trying to make will navigate a company wiki, and choose a "download page to pdf" option available on each page. For now I am just trying to get the script to log on to the wiki, navigate to the page, and select this option. I have gotten it to the page in question, now I just need to select the drop down option.

Here is the HTML

[image]

"normal ajs-menu-item" is the top level for the button and "action-export-pdf-link" is what I am trying to choose from the drop down.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('companywiki')
browser.find_by_id('login-link').click()
browser.fill('os_username', 'user')
browser.fill('os_password', 'pass')
browser.find_by_name('login').click()
browser.visit('page on company wiki')
browser.find_by_id('action-export-pdf-link').click()
```

I am running python 2.7.8, using firefox 54.0.1 and selenium 2.53.6

If anymore info is needed I will happily provide.

Comment: Can you provide more code ?

Comment: I updated the code I am using as well as the general purpose of the script I am trying to create.

Comment: I am unable to open `companywiki`, please provide the full `url`

Comment: you will not be able to access it anyway as it is on our local network. That is not the url, but a place holder as to not give out sensitive info

Comment: Why don't you use `selenium.webdriver` ?

Comment: Can you update the `page_source` in your question ? As it would be easy for me to visualize things.